# Access resx resource files from another project

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources, resx

I'm using asp.net 3.5, my solution currently has 2 projects, an API class project and a website project, within the class project I have a resource file named checkin.resx. For me to be able to access the resource files from my website project, I had to set the "Access Modifier" to public, this allowed me to use a strongly typed name to acces the resources for example: `CkiApi.Checkin.Resources.Checkin.OCKI_HeaderText`, where Checkin is the .resx file and OCKI_HeaderText is the resource key.

The problem I'm facing is that I'm unable to access the resources from front end aspx code, for example, setting a text property of a label or a validation error message. I have tried the following syntax to no avail:

```
<asp:Label AssociatedControlID="IdentMethods" EnableViewState="false" ID="lblIdentMethod" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources: CkiApi.Checkin.Resources.Checkin, OCKI_IdentificationMethod %>"></asp:Label>
```

the error I get is

> The resource object with key 'OCKI_IdentificationMethod' was not found.

but regardless of what I set the class name to, I get the same error, I'm thinking its because its trying to look in the website project but I can't figure out how to tell it to look at the API! Can anyone help?

I am able to set non server side tags using the following:

```
<div id="OckiIntroText">
    <%=CkiApi.Checkin.Resources.Checkin.OCKI_IntroText%>
</div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Resource expressions (`<%$ Resources: ClassKey, ResourceKey %>`) use [ResourceExpressionBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.resourceexpressionbuilder.aspx) class behind the scene. This class can lookup global and local resources only (in website's `App_GlobalResources` and `App_LocalResources` folders).

Instead, you can use [CodeExpressionBuilder](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx) class to access resources from different project. Here's how to use it.

Add CodeExpressionBuilder class to App_Code folder:

```
using System.CodeDom;
using System.Web.Compilation;
using System.Web.UI;

[ExpressionPrefix("Code")]
public class CodeExpressionBuilder : ExpressionBuilder
{
   public override CodeExpression GetCodeExpression(BoundPropertyEntry entry,
      object parsedData, ExpressionBuilderContext context)
   {
      return new CodeSnippetExpression(entry.Expression);
   }
}
```

Add the following to system.web/compilation section in web.config:

```
<compilation debug="false">
   ...
   <expressionBuilders>
      <add expressionPrefix="Code" type="CodeExpressionBuilder"/>
   </expressionBuilders>
</compilation>
```

Finally, you can call into strongly-typed class generated for your .resx file:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Code: ClassLibrary1.Resource1.String1 %>" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this will solve your problem but have you looked at the [HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.getglobalresourceobject.aspx) method?

I've used it to access resources in the web project, from class libraries in a framework project - so perhaps you will have luck in using it the other way around.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but unfortuantely i beleive this functionality is the same as using <%$ Resources : <class>, <key> %>, also, i wouldnt be able to bind <%= or <%# tags to a server-side attribute :(