# How to use compiled global resources in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, embedded-resource

I want to compile *App_GlobalResources/Strings.resx* into my assembly (and eventually use satellite assemblies for *Strings.es.resx, Strings.fr.resx*, etc.) but the following error occurs once the app is published:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'App_GlobalResources' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC project.
2. Add an App_GlobalResources folder and a *Strings.resx* file.
3. Set the file's **build action to 'Embedded Resource'**
4. Add a string to *Strings.resx* and use it in `HomeController.Index()`, e.g. `ViewData["Message"] = Strings.MyTest`
5. F5 to debug, works fine.
6. Publish to IIS and (since *Strings.resx* is excluded from publishing) you will get the above error in the published site.

*Can ASP.NET MVC projects use string resources compiled into the dll and if so, what am I doing wrong?*

---

Update: Here is what I see in Reflector:
[image: String Resources]

So why is the [ResourceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx) not finding them?  Isn't it supposed to [fallback to the main assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.ultimateresourcefallbacklocation.aspx) by default?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's a good starting point http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx

I setup a project just like you mentioned and got precisely the same error when I deployed to IIS6. Changing `Custom Tool` to `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator` and `Custom Tool Namespace` to `Resources` per Scott's suggestions cleared it right up.

I'd also follows Scott's lead with respect to eliminating App_GlobalResources but I got it to work just fine. That might be a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @w0rd-driben, i have build an assembly1 contain globalresource and is public as you post, but when using this assembly in another project and using code: "<%$ Resources:General, SomeKey %>" not working ... any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: @w0rd-driven, i found solution in link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222519/access-resx-resource-files-from-another-project thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is one more thing one should know about the PublicResXFileCodeGenerator - it does not work with files that has more then one dot in the file name (see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/9412f049-acd8-4a77-b73a-f3810df18376/naming-resources-files-issue-aspnet-mvc-3?forum=dlr). So the codebehind for the Strings.es.resx, Strings.fr.resx, etc. remains empty. The easy solution is to rename the files.