# Global Resources class not working in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get a value from Resource file which I have added in App_GlobalResource folder

[image]

But when I am trying to access the resource through an Action, GetGlobalResourceObject returns null and Resources class is not getting generated. What am I doing wrong in this to get the resource.

[image]

Comment: It's good that you used a graphic to show the folder, but you shouldn't use graphics for the code part. If you cut-and-paste the code block in, the website will do syntax highlighting for you, and more importantly it will show up in future searches.

Comment: Ok. Noted. I wanted to show that Resources is showing me an error and is not generated. Any way, Thanks.. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use compiled global resources in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848955/how-to-use-compiled-global-resources-in-asp-net-mvc)