# ResX files and extra application layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture, resources

we are making an web application using some big asp.net web toolkit. At the beginning we created a lot of base classes such as commands and server controls to make our work easier.

Now when we built our application using this we decided to biuld another one. To not copy all our work, and not making it from scratch we decided to separate our server controls, commands and all base clases from asp.net project and encapsulate it in another, reusable project...

Now we have the big problem, because many of those classes are using RESX files that are attached to aur asp.net application as App_GlobalResources... Where should we put them, or how can we use them to be avaible in both projects and still have a nice application architecture?

Comment: How about this - create an independant assembly (class library) with the resource files, expose the strings as public properties (make sure the namespaces are correct), then add a reference to this in your applications?

Comment: Cool idea.. I can also use this custom expression to bind them with my controls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222519/access-resx-resource-files-from-another-project... thanks for help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any resources that your server controls/commands/base classes are using need to be in the same assembly as those components.  These components have to be essentially self-contained if you want to distribute and reuse them, which means that their resources have to go along with them.

Your App_GlobalResources resx files need to be split up and the resources put into new resource files in the "reusable" assembly.