# Borrowing resources from another assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources, resx

I have project with my resources (resx files), and I want to use them as App_GlobalResources in another assembly which is asp.net project.

Now I've tried to click on Add > Existing Item > Add as link, and despite the files are visible int this folder, they are missing on the runtime and i see info that the application cannot find resource with specified key..

Any suggestions? 
Maybe there is other way to use resources from that library?

I just want it to be joinable by <% $ Resources x, y %>

Comment: Possible duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192223/resx-files-and-extra-application-layer
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222519/access-resx-resource-files-from-another-project

Comment: Not really.. I need a solution to use linked resources with <% $ Resources x,y %> syntax..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the `<%$ Resources:Key %>` syntax works only with resource files in the `App_LocalResources` special folder.

You could make the [auto-generated source file public](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ResXFileCodeGeneratorEx.aspx) (instead of internal) and use the key directly by setting the `Custom Tool` to `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the items, and set the compile mode to "Resource".  I think that was what I had to do...

Comment: Ahh well, was worth a shot.  Haven't worked with ASP, just XAML/image resources :)