# Accessing resx file from another project / assembly

Tags: c#, resources

I have a resource file in a different project and want to access eg. strings from it. How can i do this?

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222519/access-resx-resource-files-from-another-project

Comment: @MadhurAhuja: This question is about ASP.NET. Would love to see a similar answer for a non-web project.

Answer (score 6):

Make your access modifier to public .

[image]

Comment: This. I just set this modifier and ide automatically suggested referencing it in other project

Comment: If you are using a different IDE, you can change the Access Modifier by setting the ResX generator to a "Public" generator in the file's properties. In VS for Mac, this is the PublicResXFileCodeGenerator

Answer (score 4):

This is a super old question, but since it has not been answered and I just stumbled upon this problem, here are some possible solutions:

Make sure that the access modifier of the resx is set to public!

**Link to the resx file**

See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306234)

Then you either acces the string directly with

```
var translatedString = Resources.NAME_OF_THE_STRING_IN_RESX_FILE;
```

or via ResourceManager

```
var resourceManager = new ResourceManager("FULLY.QUALIFIED.NAMESPACE.NO.EXTENSION", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
var translatedString = resourceManager.GetString("NAME_OF_THE_STRING_IN_RESX_FILE");
```

**Direct access when you have a reference to the project**

```
var translatedString = [FULLY.QUALIFIED.NAMESPACE.NO.EXTENSION].NAME_OF_THE_STRING_IN_RESX_FILE;
```

Comment: To use it like `Resources.NAME_OF_THE_STRING_IN_RESX_FILE` or `Resources.LocalizedText.NAME_OF_THE_STRING_IN_RESX_FILE`, you would need to link the designer file > edit the resx file access modifier from _`No code generation`_ to _`Internal`_ or _`Public`_ which would create a new designer file > edit the csproj file to connect the linked designer file to the linked resx file to avoid using the newly created designer file > then delete the newly created designer file > _et voilà_!

Comment: The designer file must have `namespace Resources` at the top. Also, the `ResourceManager` property must have this line `global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("Resources.LocalizedText", global::System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));`. This is also near the top. This will get overwritten by Visual Studio every time you make a change to the resx file. That’s the only pain point with this solution.

Comment: The link is dead, that means the first answer does not make sense any more. Please consider fixing the link and put summary of what is inside the link.