# How to access global resources for localization in class library?

Tags: .net, localization

I've got an asp.net website (not web application) and I have localized the text for the UI using resources files (.resx). I've also got a class library which contains the business logic and there's a validation method which returns an error message. I need to localise that error message but cannot find a way to get access to the global resource file in my website. On the website, say in a code behind, I can use Resources.LocalisedText.MyErrorMessage (where LocalisedText is the name of my resource file LocalisedText.resx). However in my class library, I cannot get a reference to it.

I've found this link http://weblogs.asp.net/rinze/archive/2008/12/03/using-globalization-resources-resx-in-a-class-library-or-custom-control.aspx which says that it can be done but it doesn't seem to work for me probably because I cannot get the right namespace for the website?

Comment: I managed to find a solution and that's by adding a resource file in the class library itself. This works fine but I'd prefer to have just one resource file if possible. So if any of you out there know how to reference the .resx file in the website, let me know.

Comment: This answer should do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/35149515.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to get this to work based on the resx's designer file. If you open it up and look at the `ResourceManager` property's `get` accessor, you can basically just copy the line in order to get access to the same resources.

**Full Explanation**

First of all, you need to open your resource file's `.designer.cs` file. It should be in your Solution Explorer as in the following image:

[image: Resource file designer file location in solution explorer]

Just double click that to open it and then scan for (it should be near the top):
`internal static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager {`

In the `get` accessor, you should see it assign something to a temp variable. In my case it looked like this:

```
/*...*/ temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("Resources.Lang",
               global::System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));
```

So, based on that, I created a `ResourceManager` in the class I wanted to use in my class library like so:

```
ResourceManager lang = new ResourceManager("Resources.Lang",
                                           Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));
```

*Note 1:* Don't forget to add `using System.Resources;` and `using System.Reflection;` to the top of the file.
*Note 2:* This doesn't require adding a reference to the web project to the class library.

Then, I just call the `GetString` method on my `lang` variable to get the resources I want.
E.g. `lang.GetString("MyErrorMessage")`.
It's not as elegant as calling `Resources.Lang.MyErrorMessage`, but it gets the job done.

Hope this helps. Drop a comment below if you have any questions.

Comment: There is a way to do it that makes it so that you do not need to use `GetString`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35149515.

Answer (score -1):

```
new ResourceManager("YourRessourceName", Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()).GetString("MyLocalizedString");
```

here you build a ressourceManager using the executing assembly (your web site), "YourRessourcenName" is the name of your ressource file without the resx and the language.

Comment: Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() seems to return null for a web application.