# resx sharing between projects

Tags: c#, .net

I have a solution named 'mySolution' with two projects:

- ProjectA
- ProjectB

ProjectA contains a resource file named 'mySolutionResources.resx'.
ProjectB refrences projectA, but can't access resources in mySolutionResources.

After some research I found that: "resource classes are all marked as internal".

My question now is:

If I want to maintain only one 'mySolutionResources.resx', how can I do to get access to it from projectB? If it is not possible, is there another aproach ?

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873623/accessing-resx-file-from-another-project-assembly) a similar question

Comment: @Jonesy That doesn't deserve to be here at all.

Comment: What you posted... the link in one answer simply signposts _another_ link here on SO. Really.

Comment: When you have access to both projects, why don't you make the resources in `ProjectA` public?

Comment: @Gorgsenegger Tks. But how can i do it public, by default it is internal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you open the 'mySolutionResources.resx' (in designer) and on top you will see option of **Access Modifier: [Internal]**. You can change this value to **[Public]**. This should expose the resource data to other projects if referenced.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than sharing resx files, I would prefer to write code in one assembly to expose the resources externally (depending on the nature of the resources). If you  don't want that 'sharing' code to be public, you could always use [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx)