# How to return resource in asp.net view from method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have some html code that I want to replace with text from resources.

My class looks like:

```
 public static class ResourceParser
    {
        public static string GetTextFromResource(string keyValue)
        {
            ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("pl", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            return rm.GetString(keyValue);
        }
    }
```

When I access resources from my view this way:

```
@Resources.pl.accept;
```

it works and displays the value I want.

When I do it like this:

```
@ResourceParser.GetTextFromResource("accept");
```

there is an exception

> MissingManifestResourceException "Could not find
>   any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral
>   culture. Make sure "Servers.Resources.resources" was correctly
>   embedded or linked into assembly "myProject" at compile time, or that
>   all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."

Comment: What is the name of the resource file and what is the file path?

Comment: See if [this link](https://developerslogblog.wordpress.com/2017/11/12/how-to-fix-could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate-for-the-specified-culture/) helps. Cannot post as answer yet as that would be just guessing

Comment: @Andrei I've changed to embedded resources and still the same problem occurs. Now The part that was working before is not working :P

Comment: @Haldo the resource file name is pl.resx. The resource file is in different project actually

Comment: What is the namespace of the project?  I think it should be loaded using full namespace: `new ResourceManager('Full.Namespace.WithoutExtension')`.

Comment: Does [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873623/accessing-resx-file-from-another-project-assembly) help?

Comment: @Haldo so if I have Solution "Name1.Name2" and then the Project "Name3.Name4" and inside the project a folder "Folder1" and the file pl.resx the path would be like  new ResourceManager("Name1.Name2.Name3.Name4.Folder1.pl") ?

Comment: @Alice Not sure tbh. I'd try `ResourceManager("Name3.Name4.Folder1.pl")`.

Comment: I've tried different variations and it seems that it still doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184411/discussion-between-haldo-and-alice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working somehow.

In the meantime I've added this method:

```
 protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.UserLanguages != null)
            {
                string culture = Request.UserLanguages[0];

                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture);
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture);
            }
        }
```

to my Global.asax.cs file

and I've change the code a bit:

```
public static string GetTextFromResource(string keyValue)
        {
            var path = "ProjectName.Folder.pl";

            var res_manager = new ResourceManager(path, typeof(pl).Assembly);

            return res_manager.GetString(keyValue);
        }
```