# .NET MAUI choose different resource file depending on project

Tags: c#, maui, resx

I have a project where I have a "base project" with resources as fallback files. And I have multiple "branded apps" with the same view as XAML files but with some resources that should override the fallback files.

The views are currently located in my base project.

How can I tell my view that it should prefer the resource from the "branded app" instead of the base project? Sadly, it is not allowed to move the views from the base project to the "branded apps".

I did already tried to load the resource with `GetEntryAssembly()` but I get a null return there, so no reference on the main project.

Sadly I have no idea where to start so I could need some help.

[Project Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPDTw.png)

Comment: we have a XF app that has several different "brands" built from the same codebase.  We use a pre-build script that adds the appropriate images and icons to each project before the build starts

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinki am going with the answer from Jason and use a pre-build script that adds the appropriate images and icons to each project before the build starts.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post:
[Accessing resx file from another project / assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873623/accessing-resx-file-from-another-project-assembly)

I struggle to understand exactly what you mean, but I think this post has solution to your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).