# How to access another assembly's .resx?

Tags: c#, .net, resx

I have an assembly which contains, among other things, a Messages.resx which contains strings of GUI messages such as Yes, No, OK, Cancel, Open, etc. My project references this assembly. How can I use them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the resource editor just mark the resources as `public`. By default the access modifier is `internal`. Then you can use it normally.

If making it public is not an option then use `InternalsVisibleTo` assembly level attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Use  [ResourceManager Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx)

```
  // Retrieve the resource.
  ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("Messages" ,Assembly.Load(assemblyPath));
  string greeting = rm.GetString("Greeting");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: apparently this one is referring to .resource files, not .resx
It throws an exception saying Messages.resource is not found

Comment: oops, did you found this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222519/access-resx-resource-files-from-another-project)?