# How to read the properties of an .resx file in a Web site project of asp. Net from a dll assembly

Tags: c#, .net, dll, resx

I'm new in .Net and working with two projects in c# a class library project(dll)  and a website asp project.

I need to read some properties from a file .resx that is in the App_GlobalResources folder of the website.

Is there a way to read these properties in the .resx website file  from a dll assembly more specifically in the method onPreRender??

Thanks for you attention

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you are having some problems with structuring and dependencies in your solution. (Trying to reference the website from a DLL)

Generally speaking, your DLL should not need to access the resources of the website on its own - you should only pass them in through as parameters when calling various methods that are contained in the DLL itself.

Have you thought about migrating the resource file to the DLL? 
That would allow both DLL and the website to read from it.

Another option would be to migrate the setting you need to the .config file which you can read by using the **ConfigurationManager** class ( [MSND Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) )

You should be able to use it like this, even from your Code repository project:

```
string settingValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YouSettingNameHere"].ToString();
```

However, if you really want to keep your current solution structure you can follow the answer that *Pavel Chuchuva* gave on a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222519/access-resx-resource-files-from-another-project).