# Visual Studio and msbuild produces .net 4 resources dlls instead of 3.5

Tags: msbuild, .net-3.5, resx, al.exe

If you follow the instructions on [Access resx resource files from another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222519/access-resx-resource-files-from-another-project) to create translations using resx files, when the project is .net 3.5 it is not working and it seems to ignore specified culture.

It seems that the problem is specific with my build chain.
I have installed

- .net 4.8
- Windows SDK 10 (I have this C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools)
- Visual Studio 2019

When I inspect the output DLLs using jetbrain's dotPeek, I see that the satellite DLLs are .net 4.0

A colleague doesn't have .net 4.8 or Windows SDK 10 and he produces satellite DLLs .net 3.5
He has Windows SDK 7.

The problem AFAIK is with the al.exe that outputs these DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed with `al.exe`. The configuration in `al.exe.config` was specifying that it should support `v4.0` of dotnet.

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
</startup>
```

And by changing it to:

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
</startup>
```

solved it.